# Number of ${\tt NAND}$-gates needed to build any $n$-ary Boolean function

Tags: boolean-functions

Are there positive integers $k,c$ with the following property?

> Whenever $n$ is a positive integer, then any function $$f:\{0,1\}^n\to\{0,1\}$$ can be built using at most $n^k+c$ ${\tt NAND}$-gates with 2 inputs and 1 output.

Comment: This is not a research-level question, and should have been asked at https://cs.stackexchange.com . Any textbook on circuit complexity will tell you that the maximal circuit size required by boolean functions in $n$ variables is $(1+o(1))2^n/n$ (and this is pretty much independent of the choice of the basic gate types). An $\Omega(2^n/n)$ lower bound actually follows by a trivial counting argument, as there are $2^{2^n}$ distinct functions, but only $2^{O(s\log(s+n))}$ circuits of size $s$.

Comment: Thanks Emil for your helpful information and the counting argument that escaped me. Will delete the question. Happy new year!